# Best practice for only including scripts on certain pages?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm building a static site with PHP includes for the head tag but certain pages will utilize an image gallery plugin that I don't want to slow down the whole website with by loading it unnecessarily.

Right now I've got `<?php echo "$scripts";?>` in my head.php and I only define the $scripts variable on the few pages I'm actually using the plugin. Is there a better technique I should be using? Thanks!

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Why don't you separate your included script into two scripts, let's say HEAD1 and HEAD2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your technique is fine for a simple website.  To be honest I don't think it's completely necessary, the browser is going to cache the CSS and JavaScript so even if it is in each head file it's not reloading the scripts/CSS every single page load.  I wouldn't worry about it, but it's ultimately up to you.

Edit - you don't need to place quotes around your $script variable though and you should be checking it before using it, since you won't always have it set.

```
if(isset($scripts)) {
    echo $scripts;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the answer I needed. Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTML 5 workers designed for big scripts so your page won't become unusable. Check it out, you can see concepts and examples here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html#fbid=CRCsYDbx2st

Second, if You don't want to use Web workers, you can try to include your javascripts before  tag, instead of  tag, so most of the page will probably still show up.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question. The question is regarding page load, download size and number of requests, not about executing heavy JS off the main thread.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I did not realise that was your really question; I could not tell it from my view.